# Multiple rows hiding in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, row, information-hiding

I have an Excel sheet that I'm trying to put multiple condition to hide rows.  2 of them is hiding some rows if a specific cells equal 0, one of them is hiding some rows if a specific cell has a specific word and lastly hiding rows if there is zero in a specific column.  It seems to work when I do separately but I can't seem to make it work jointly. Some of the rows could be included in more than one condition. Please note I'm very novice at that.

Here's what I tried:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xRg As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim R3 As Range
Dim R1 As Range
    


Set R1 = Union(Rows("61:61"), Rows("68:69"), Rows("72:72"), Rows("91:106"), Rows("117:125"), Rows("144:155"), Rows("157:158"), Rows("164:164"), Rows("166:166"))
Set R2 = Union(Rows("49:52"), Rows("65:129"))
Set R3 = Union(Rows("53:57"), Rows("130:161"))



Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each xRg In Range("E8:E153")
            If xRg.Value = 0 Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg


    If Range("E$15").Value = 0 Then
    
       R3.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
        R3.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
      
    If Range("E$14").Value = 0 Then
    
       R2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
        R2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    
        
    If Range("B$3").Value = "USD" Then
        R1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
        R1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

        
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better specify the result you want to get; is there a priority in the conditions you impose?
For example, between

```
Range("E$15") = 0
```

and

```
xRg.Value = 0
```

which should prevail?

Try reversing the instructions

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim R3 As Range
    Dim R1 As Range

    Set R1 = Union(Rows("61:61"), Rows("68:69"), Rows("72:72"), Rows("91:106"), Rows("117:125"), Rows("144:155"), Rows("157:158"), Rows("164:164"), Rows("166:166"))
    Set R2 = Union(Rows("49:52"), Rows("65:129"))
    Set R3 = Union(Rows("53:57"), Rows("130:161"))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    R3.EntireRow.Hidden = Range("E$15") = 0
    R2.EntireRow.Hidden = Range("E$14") = 0
    R1.EntireRow.Hidden = Range("B$3") = "USD"
    For Each xRg In Range("E8:E153")
        xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = xRg.Value = 0
    Next xRg
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

PS: It doesn't make much sense to use an if..then construct to assign a boolean value to a boolean variable.

Then you have to evaluate the condition with the lowest priority first and last the one with the highest priority.

Priority: 1,2,3,4

Code: 4,3,2,1

Comment: Thank you ! It doesn't quite work.  I'd say priority of the events would be R3=R2, then R1, then xRg